# calculate the square root of a number to at least one decimal place in PHP

Tags: php, recursion

I need to calculate the square root of a number to at least one decimal place without using the built-in PHP mathematical functions. In other words, we can only use multiplication, division, addition and subtraction.

Example: `calculate_square_root(56)` would result in: `7.4`

Note: I need a recursion based code for above problem

Please help anyone to sort out the problem and thanks in advance.

Comment: Homework? Else why not simply use sqrt()

Comment: Reinventing the wheel or is it homework ? In either case you should provide what you have done so far :)

Comment: That's got to be a homework. Regardless... Start with an algorithm. Write down the algorithm on a piece of paper (and I do mean paper, not a computer screen).  The think about how to implement it.

Comment: http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~jst/cse/131/Notes/SquareRoot/sqrt.html

Comment: Yup. Giving him a free answer with a complimentary downvote.

Comment: If we're at the subject, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root ;)

Comment: Why are you demanding that the solution employ recursion and that the solution cannot use the `sqrt` function? These are artificial constraints that are completely impractical.

Comment: There is no reason not to use sqrt. Use sqrt!

Answer (score 2):

Simple.....

```
function calculate_square_root($number) {
  return parseInt($number^0.5*10)/10;
}
```

**edit** sorry: here you go without built in...

**edit2** as pointed out in the comments below, the caret `^` is not for power/exponent, but is for XOR. So This answer is **WRONG**.

Comment: He specified to not use built in PHP functions !

Comment: have you read what OP state in question? let me give you a hint: "without using the built-in PHP mathematical functions. In other words, we can only use multiplication, division, addition and subtraction."

Comment: ok ok ok... gee wiz. here's ur rocket science :) I can use parseInt() ?

Comment: @nl-x, "we can only use multiplication, division, addition and subtraction"

Comment: Those constraints are unreasonable. The built-in functions are available in all versions of PHP. There's no reason not to use them.

Comment: @nl-x In php there is no "power" operator, ^ is a bitwise (XOR) operator. Use pow() instead. For bigger exponents use bcpow() !

Comment: he wants a "recursion based code"...

Comment: Demanding recursion is absurd here. The answer will be much slower and less accurate than just using the built-in `sqrt`. Just use it. That's why it's there.

Comment: it's not absurd if it's for homework...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I believe `pow` is forbidden

Comment: @JanDvorak which leads that this is not the desired answer :p

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV and yet nobody downvotes.

Comment: @JanDvorak It is not a "wrong" answer, it's just not the desired one. Since nl-x has put some efforts in it, I actually upvoted it.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV it's wrong in the sense it doesn't answer the _question_ in its entirety. It is also wrong in the sense it uses XOR as if it were `pow` (I could fix the latter, but not the former).

Comment: The original answer with `sqrt` and `round` was fine. It provides a solution rather than solving the problem.